# How to change footnote number position without losing other properties?

Tags: xetex, footnotes, xepersian

I have the following document:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  %\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
  %\usepackage{scrextend}
  \usepackage{zref-perpage}
  \zmakeperpage{footnote}
  \usepackage{xepersian}
  \settextfont{XB Yas}
  \setlatintextfont[Scale=.9]{Times New Roman}
  \setdigitfont[Scale=.9]{XB Yas}
  \begin{document}
   some text\footnote{Right To left footnote}
   some text\LTRfootnote{English footnote(Left to Right)}
  \end{document}
```

I want to lower the footnote numbers (footnote marks on bottom of page) and it position be on base line without losing other properties of footnote. because I have a big project that any changes on footnote becomes a big problem on edition. any suggestion would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by using the following code

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em
\noindent\hbox to 1em{}%
\llap{\if@RTL\else\latinfont\fi\@thefnmark\,\,}#1}
\makeatother
```